# The probability distribution function of uniform random variables is as given

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Given $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_n$ where each $U_i \sim U[0,1]$, then use uniqueness theorem to show probability distribution function of $X = U_1 + U_2 + \ldots +U_n$ (sum of independent uniform random variables) is:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(x-k)^{n-1}_{+}$$

The uniqueness theorem says the characteristic function uniquely determines the probability distribution. The characteristic function for $U_i$ in this case will be $\phi_i(x)=$ $\int_{0}^{1} e^{itx}dx = \frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$. Next lets find the characteristic function for X, this will be:

$$\phi_X(t)$ = E(e^{it(U_1+\ldots+U_n)}) = \left(\frac{e^{it}-1}{it} \right)^n $$

From discussion in comments, to apply uniqueness theorem here, we consider a random variable Y such that Y has distribution f(x). Then $\phi_Y(t) = E(e^{iYt}) = \int_{0}^nf(x)e^{ixt}dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{n}(x-k)^{n-1}e^{ixt}dx$. I am not sure how the computation goes from here, but we want to show $\phi_Y(t) = \phi_X(t)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks I fixed it

Comment: The characteristic function of the sum is $\left(\frac{e^{-t}-1}{it}\right)^n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Agreed, adding more info in.

Comment: I had a typo, numerator is $e^{it}-1$. Now find the characteristic function of the random variable that has density $f(t)$. You may want to replace the index of summation by $k$, or do like electrical engineers and use $j$ for $\sqrt{-1}$. So integrate $f(x)e^{ixt}$ over a suitable interval.

Comment: I have made the edits. We have found the characteristic function of random variable X, $\phi_X(t)$, we are told this has density f(x). What do we want to achieve by integrating $f(x)e^{ixt}$, don't we work with $\phi_X(t)$ now?

Comment: We are not told it has density $f(x)$. You have found the characteristic function of $X$. Now find the characteristic function of a random variable $Y$ that has density $f(x)$. If this characteristic function turns out to be the same as the one you computed for $X$, you will know that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution (by Uniqueness Theorem).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ohhh, that makes perfect sense! So then in your above comment did you mean to say that integrating $f(x)e^{ixt}$ will result in the characteristic function of Y?

Comment: Yes it will, since we want $E(e^{iYt})$.

Comment: In that case we want $\int_{0}^{n} f(x)e^{ixt}dx$, so the interesting part to integrate would be $\int_{0}^{n} (x-k)^{n-1}e^{ixt}$, not sure how to compute the last integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that your last expression

$$\phi_Y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{n}(x-k)^{n-1}e^{ixt}dx$$

**is not exactly correct**. In the sum you have $(x-k)_+$ which is $0$ unless $x>k$. So it should be

$$\phi_Y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{k}^{n}(x-k)^{n-1}e^{ixt}dx$$

Now, let $u=x-k$ and $J_{n,m}=\int_{0}^{n-k}u^{n-m}e^{iut}du$:

$$\phi_Y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{e^{ikt}}{(n-1)!}J_{n,1}$$

$$J_{n,1}=\frac{1}{it}\int_{0}^{n-k}u^{n-1}de^{iut}=\frac{1}{it}\left[e^{iut}u^{n-1}|_{u=0}^{n-k}-(n-1)J_{n,2}\right]=...=$$

$$=e^{iut}\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-j)!(it)^j}u^{n-j}|_{u=0}^{n-k}=$$

$$=e^{i(n-k)t}\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-j)!(it)^j}(n-k)^{n-j}+(-1)^n\frac{(n-1)!}{(it)^n}$$

Now plug this into $\phi_Y(t)$, change summation order in the first term and note that $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m=0$ for $m<n$. So that the first term is just $0$. What is left is just:

$$\phi_Y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{e^{ikt}}{(n-1)!}(-1)^n\frac{(n-1)!}{(it)^n}=\frac{(e^{it}-1)^n}{(it)^n}$$